# Checking class isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have an abelian group G of order 441. I am trying to give all possible isomorphism classes. So far I have:

$Z_{441},$

$Z_{49} +Z_9 $ since 9 and 49 are coprime and + means direct product

$Z_7+Z_7+Z_3+Z_3$

I understand that for $U(p^k)$ is isomorphic to $Z_{p^k-p^{k-1}}$ for p being an odd prime. But does that mean a possible class is $Z_{42}+Z_6$? I dont think it does because you dont get 441.

Lastly how can one tell if you have all possible classes? Is there a formula or like a number that divides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each (nontrivial) finite abelian group $G$ there are *unique* $1< n_1 |\dots | n_r$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_{n_1} \oplus \dots \oplus Z_{n_r}$.

Overserve that one has that order of $G$ is $n_1  \dots n_r$.

Thus to solve the problem you need find all factorizations of $441$ that give an ascending chain (by divisibility).

These are, $441$, $21 \times 21$, $7 \times 63$, $3 \times 147$.

---

Alternatively, there are up to the order unique primepowers $q_1, \dots, q_s$ such that
$G$ is isomorphic to $Z_{q_1} \oplus \dots \oplus Z_{q_s}$.

Here you need to find the factorizations of $441$ into prime powers, they are $3 \times 3 \times 7 \times 7$, $9 \times 7 \times 7$, $3 \times 3 \times 49$ and $9 \times 49$.

---

You can use either, but do not give both since for example $Z_{9} \oplus Z_{49}$ is isomorphic to $Z_{441}$.

There is also a formula for the number: it is $p(v_1) \dots p(v_k)$ where $n= p_{1}^{v_1} \dots  p_{k}^{v_k}$ is the factorization as a product of distinct primes and $p$ denotes the number of partitions.
In your case you have $441= 3^2 7^2$ so the number is $p(2)p(2)= 2 \times 2$, as the only partitions of $2$ are $2$ and $1+1$.

Comment: so the classes are 441, 3x3x7x7, 9x7x7, and 3x3x49.

Comment: Yes. Of course you would have to write it out in the way you did in the question $Z_{441}$; $Z_3 + Z_3 +Z_7 + Z_ 7 $ and so on. Just one note: if you write it as you do it is somewhat non-systematic since you mix the two approaches, but it is correct.

Comment: yea, i understand you. i just followed after yours to make it easier